# Objective-c calculator program by using CommandLineTool

Tags: objective-c

Hi guys I've created a main.m file a calculator.h and calculator.m file

before writing down my code my problem is that the program doesn't ask for the operator it only asks for 1st and 2nd number.

here are my codes for the main.m

```
int num1,num2;
    char op;

    Calculator *myCalculator=[[Calculator alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"Please Enter The First Number");
    scanf("%i",&num1);

    NSLog(@"Please Choose a mathematical operation '+', '-', '*', '/' :");
    scanf("%c",&op);

    NSLog(@"Please Enter The Second Number");
    scanf("%i",&num2);



    switch (op) {
        case '+':

            NSLog(@"The Result is : %i",[myCalculator Add:num1 :num2]);
            break;

        case '-':

            NSLog(@"The Result is : %i",[myCalculator Sub:num1 :num2]);
            break;


        case '*':
            NSLog(@"The Result is : %i",[myCalculator Mul:num1 :num2]);
            break;

        case '/':
            NSLog(@"The Result is : %i",[myCalculator Div:num1 :num2]);
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown Operator");
            break;
    }
```

and my codes for the implementation are as follows:

```
-(int) Add:(int)num1 :(int)num2
{
    return num1+num2;
}

-(int) Sub:(int)num1 :(int)num2
{
    return num1-num2;
}

-(int) Mul:(int)num1 :(int)num2
{
    return num1*num2;
}

-(int) Div:(int)num1 :(int)num2
{
    return num1/num2;
}
```

any help will be appreciated thanks in advance !

Comment: BTW:  methods should start w/a lowercase and be something like `addNumber:toNumber:` instead of `add::`.  Objective-C tends to be quite descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't done anything like this in awhile, but when I made a small text based RPG battle system I ran into a similar problem. The user presses enter after inputting a number, right? The number will get scanned into `num1` and the newline character will get scanned into `op`. Log the value of `op` before your switch.

Comment: yes the user presses enter after inputing the value of number and it's scanned into num1. I haven't understand what you meant by log the value of op before switch?

Comment: @AsImGunduz The user pressed enter. The input now holds a number, followed by a newline character. The number is scanned in, it asks for a character and then the newline that the user entered to accept is scanned into `op`. Before your `switch` statement, use `NSLog` to find out what is contained in `op` like `NSLog(@"op contains: %c", op)`. If you get a newline, the above occurred. One way to solve this is to just put the second scan line twice, or use `getchar()` once beforehand to skip the newline.